# Linking in assembly files with Mingw

Tags: assembly, mingw

All,

I am currently in the process of changing the compiler that we use to be MingGw.  At this point I have MinGw compiling all of the files but I cannot get it to link in the assembly files that I have.  I have checked and the assembly files have compiled into object files.  I also have checked with the "-verbose" option that those object files are included in the link process.  However all I get is error messages about "undefined reference to...." over and over.

I am not sure what I am missing in order to get the assembly files to link in correctly.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do symbol names in asm files begin with _ (underscore)? For example following example compiled with gcc 4.9.2 from MinGW-W64 works as expected on 32-bit XP:

**----- file asmtest.c -----**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int add(int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("The result is: %d\n", add(3, 5));

  return 0;
}
```

**----- file asmadd.S -----**

```
.section .text

.global _add

_add:
    movl 4(%esp), %eax
    movl 8(%esp), %ebx
    addl %ebx, %eax
    ret
```

**----- compile command -----**

```
gcc -Wall -o asmtest asmtest.c asmadd.S
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I am not sure where it talks about this requirement in the documentation but this did the trick